# C++ templates. How to make this code prettier?

Tags: c++, templates, coding-style

suppose I have a class-template like so:

```
template<typename CONTAINER, typename param>
struct someClass {
    static void foo (CONTAINER someContainer) {
        //some code which needs to know both the container as well as its parameter
    }
};
```

And now I want to pass a vector as well as the type with which the vector template was specialized with:

```
int main () {
    std::vector<int> someVector;
    someClass<std::vector<int>, int>::foo(someVector); 
}
```

Is there any way to make this nicer so that I can use:

```
    someClass<std::vector<int>>::foo(someVector);
```

?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is needing a code review. try codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: think about a typedef

Comment: Standard containers all have a nested typedef `value_type`, which you can make use of. (Make sure you look up when `typename` is required, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want:

```
template<typename CONTAINER, typename param = typename CONTAINER::value_type>
struct someClass {
    static void foo (CONTAINER someContainer) {
        //some code which needs to know both the container as well as its parameter
    }
};
```

Then you can use `param` as a normal type.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports template template parameters, you can use it to solve this issue. Check this link for details on template template parameters: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=376878

Comment: You can't portably pass `std::vector` as a template template parameter, since the implementation is allowed to add extra template parameters  to `vector`.

Comment: @AlanStokes if you use a variadic template template like this template<template<typename...> class CONTAINER, typename VALUE> it should work despite the defaulted allocator param.